# MySql - order by monthname

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I am trying to order mysql query by month name like:

```
January --  5
February -- 2
March    -- 5
and so on
```

Here is my query, but its not ordering:

```
SELECT leave_balance.balance, MonthName(leave_balance.date_added) AS month 
FROM leave_balance WHERE leave_balance.staff_id_staff = $iid 
GROUP BY month,  leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type 
HAVING leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type = $leaveBalTypID 
ORDER BY month
```

Kindly tell me where I am doing wrong

Comment: What is it currently coming out as?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you can specify like

```
ORDER BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March',...)


SELECT leave_balance.balance, MonthName(leave_balance.date_added) AS month 
FROM leave_balance WHERE leave_balance.staff_id_staff = $iid 
GROUP BY month,  leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type 
HAVING leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type = $leaveBalTypID 
ORDER BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March',...,'December');
```

Answer (score 9):

Just add this at the end of your query statement:

```
ORDER BY str_to_date(MONTH,'%M')
```

If column name changes in the future you will not need to worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

try using the built in month function to get the month's number and order by that. For example:

```
order by month(leave_balance.date_added)
```

Answer (score 2):

simply order by `leave_balance.date_added` field. By default it will sort by month.