# Sort datatable by month name column

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I  want to sort datatable by month name and the month names are in french how would I do that . I have searched alot but didn't get any result. Any will be of great use . Thank you

Comment: what have you searched ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have searched? I dont think so

```
ORDER BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March',...)


SELECT leave_balance.balance, MonthName(leave_balance.date_added) AS month 
FROM leave_balance WHERE leave_balance.staff_id_staff = $iid 
GROUP BY month,  leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type 
HAVING leave_balance.leave_type_id_leave_type = $leaveBalTypID 
ORDER BY FIELD(MONTH,'January','February','March',...,'December');
```

Duplicate from:
[MySql - order by monthname](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15607516/mysql-order-by-monthname)

First google result

Datatables, my bad, and still, first result ;)

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", 
    "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November", "December"];
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['month-name-asc'] = function (x, y) {
    var xPos, yPos;
    jQuery.each(monthNames, function (k, v) {
        if (x == v) xPos = k;
        if (y == v) yPos = k
    });
    return ((xPos < yPos) ? -1 : ((xPos > yPos) ? 1 : 0));
};
jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort['month-name-desc'] = function (x, y) {
    var xPos, yPos;
    jQuery.each(monthNames, function (k, v) {
        if (x == v) xPos = k
        if (y == v) yPos = k
    });
    return ((xPos > yPos) ? -1 : ((xPos < yPos) ? 1 : 0));
};
```

http://drmsite.blogspot.com/2013/08/datatables-custom-sort-by-month-name.html

Comment: OP isn't refering to any queries but wants to sort Datatables.

Comment: Despite being quoted in the answer I'd change that way of doing things now and instead use momentjs to sort the months, that way momentjs takes all the heartache from parsing the language. Remember to set the correct `moment.locale()` though! Do you have a JSFiddle up with the code and I'll take a squint?

Answer (score 0):

Update for Datatables 1.10+

```
var monthNames = ["January", "February", "March", 
    "April", "May", "June", 
    "July", "August", "September", 
    "October", "November", "December"];

   jQuery.extend(jQuery.fn.dataTableExt.oSort, {
        "month-name-asc": function (a, b) {
            var xPos = 0, yPos = 0;
            $.each(monthNames, function (k, v) {
                if (a == v) xPos = k;
                if (b == v) yPos = k;
            });
            return ((xPos < yPos) ? -1 : ((xPos > yPos) ? 1 : 0));
        },

        "month-name-desc": function (a, b) {
            var xPos = 0, yPos = 0;
            $.each(monthNames, function (k, v) {
                if (a == v) xPos = k;
                if (b == v) yPos = k;
            });
            return ((xPos > yPos) ? -1 : ((xPos < yPos) ? 1 : 0));
        }
    });
```